# Criteria add order as column operation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I usually order in hibernate using

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("myField"));
```

How can I write this statement in Hibernate without using hsql?

```
select * from my_table order by (deletion_date - creation_date) asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate queries through objects generated by mapping to the database, each table in your database will become a class, so when we consult with Hibernate we refer to the object and not directly to the table. Example : FROM Class1 c

However, it is also possible implemetanción Querys Native within the same Hibernate, which means a common query in Hibernate. Example : SELECT * FROM table

Practically, it depends how you want to work, but in my opinion, if you're using Hibernate, then works with the mappings generated, working with objects.